# Calculate Field: Remove last character in string based on condition

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a list of route numbers in a geodatabase that contain directions on the end of them (123W, 123E, 1500S, etc.). I need to remove the last digit if it is N,S,W,E but leave other letters.

I'm very new at Python and after searching around, came up with this. It was working when I created this code block in ArcGIS Pro but after coming back to it later, it's not doing anything when I run the Calculate Field except returning the original value:

```
def trimDir(dir):
    dirlist = ['W','E','S','N']
    if dir.endswith(tuple(dirlist)):
        dir2 = dir[:-1]
        return dir2
    else:
        return dir
```

How can this be done?

Comment: replace the `if` statement with `if len(dir)>0 and dir[-1] in dirList:`

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Your solution did work but I did finally figure out that I had an extra whitespace at the end of my route numbers which was why the code wasn't working. Once I eliminated that, my code worked. So both of these solutions are good!

Comment: By digit you mean last letter, or last digit/number? 123A should be 123 or 12A?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are trying with should work, so maybe you are not calling the function properly.  Do not name a function or variable [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir), it is a built in function, maybe that is causing the function to fail.

```
def trim(x) :
    dont_keep = ('N','S','W','E')
    if x.endswith(dont_keep):
        return x[:-1]
    else:
        return x
```

Call with

```
trim(!yourfieldnamehere!)
```

( I use dir to check what can be done with an object. For example if I cant remember a method name, but know 'is' is in the method name, I do `[m for m in dir('a string') if 'is' in m.lower()]` and get:

```
['isalnum',
 'isalpha',
 'isascii',
 'isdecimal',
 'isdigit',
 'isidentifier',
 'islower',
 'isnumeric',
 'isprintable',
 'isspace',
 'istitle',
 'isupper']
```